# How to override AWS Amplify Api domain endpoint

Tags: aws-amplify

I have added a custom domain to the API Gateway due to CORS/Cookies/Infosec and other fun reasons.

I then added the following code to *hack* the correct domain into my Amplify configuration:

```js
import { Amplify, API } from "aws-amplify"

const myfunc () => {
  const amplifyEndpoint = API._restApi._options.endpoints[0]
  Amplify.configure({
    aws_cloud_logic_custom: [
      {
        ...amplifyEndpoint,
        endpoint: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL || amplifyEndpoint.endpoint,
      },
    ]
  })

  const response = await API.post("MyApiNameHere", "/some-endpoint", {data:"here"})
}
```

This works but a) is this *really* the correct way to do it? and b) I'm seeing a weird issue whereby the first API.post request of the day from a user is missing the `authorization` & `x-amz-security-token` headers that I expect Amplify to be magically providing. If a user refreshes the page, the headers are sent and everything works as expected.

**[edit]** turns out my missing headers issue is unrelated to this override, so still need to get to the bottom of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more correct place looks to be in the `index.js`:

```js
import { Amplify, API } from "aws-amplify"
import awsExports from "./aws-exports"

Amplify.configure(awsExports)

const amplifyEndpoint = API._restApi._options.endpoints[0]
Amplify.configure({
  aws_cloud_logic_custom: [
    {
      ...amplifyEndpoint,
      endpoint: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL || amplifyEndpoint.endpoint,
    },
  ]
})
```

That way it's done once - rather than needing to be done in each API call.

Naturally you would need some more complicated logic if you were dealing with multiple endpoints.